# "Insanity is wasting your life as a nothing"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I don't understand the indefinite article in a line from the movie *wanted*.
Why "**a** nothing"? Shouldn't *nothing* be a noncount noun?

> Wesley: You're insane.
>
> Sloan: No. Insanity is wasting your life as **a** nothing when you have the blood of a killer flowing in your veins.

Comment: Does "as a nobody" help?

Comment: You can be "nothing but a big nothing". *He ain't nuthin but a big nuthin*. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a%20big%20nothing%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more understandable this way:

> No. Insanity is wasting your life as **a nobody** when you have the blood of a killer flowing in your veins.

meaning his life as such would be worth nothing. As for the usage in your example, see [*nothing*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nothing):

> 5. b. a person considered to be of no value or importance

Comment: I thought it would be more common to say/hear _You are nothing_ as opposed to _You are a nothing._

Comment: "a nothing" individualizes it. Compare "You are *foolish*" vs. You are *a fool*". *nothing* is a quality, while *a nothing* is an object. Both ways are likely but the meaning is a bit different.